# WPF and SharePoint 2010

Tags: wpf, sharepoint

We are in the early phases for a big project that will be using SharePoint 2010 (not using webpart, but a whole independent application that will run inside Sharepoint).Out project is Web-enabled (we don;t want a Windows application). The options we have to code our project with are:

-Asp.Net Application
-WPF 4
-SilverLight 4.

My question, what are the pros and cons for using WPF for such a project? 
Im choosing WPF because i know it's larger than Silverlight and we have more options with it. Is that right? Are there any limitations with WPF/Sharepoint 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is more platform-independant and has a smaller framework.
Other than that there are no restrictions / problems in WPF / Sharepoint cooperation.